error trying to install a script from an library app namely Helium which backs up your android app data to computer
https://github.com/yutclubza/YutClubZa/blob/master/Helium-Desktop-Installer-and-Android-App.md
here is the error when i try to run the SH script command in terminal
Code: Select all
yuks@puks:~/Downloads/linux$ ls
adb  README  run.sh
yuks@puks:~/Downloads/linux$ ./run.sh 
./adb: error while loading shared libraries: libncurses.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

./adb: error while loading shared libraries: libncurses.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
yuks@puks:~/Downloads/linux$ 

i have installed the android-sdk to try to fix this but still no avail i cant seem to find the ncurseslib file it does find something in snapshot but not the version required or higher even if i try to install it says its already installed

whats the next step? i tried this
Code: Select all

yuks@puks:~/Downloads/linux$ locate libncurse

Code: Select all

"
.....
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncurses++.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncurses++w.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncurses.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncurses.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncurses.so.6
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncurses.so.6.4
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncursesw.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncursesw.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncursesw.so.6
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncursesw.so.6.4
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/plugins/gui/libncurses_plugin.so
/usr/share/doc/libncurses-dev
/usr/share/doc/libncurses6
/usr/share/doc/libncursesw6
/var/cache/apt/archives/libncurses-dev_6.4+20240113-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libncurses-dev:amd64.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libncurses-dev:amd64.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libncurses6:amd64.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libncurses6:amd64.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libncurses6:amd64.shlibs
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libncurses6:amd64.symbols
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libncurses6:amd64.triggers
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libncursesw6:amd64.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libncursesw6:amd64.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libncursesw6:amd64.shlibs
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libncursesw6:amd64.symbols
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libncursesw6:amd64.triggers
/var/lib/flatpak/runtime/org.freedesktop.Platform/x86_64/22.08/89f5b42b081f8cfcf7fbb1d858b82af06fe19681e6f6ea4c3b769dcb6c1ac295/files/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncurses.so.6
/var/lib/flatpak/runtime/org.freedesktop.Platform/x86_64/22.08/89f5b42b081f8cfcf7fbb1d858b82af06fe19681e6f6ea4c3b769dcb6c1ac295/files/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncurses.so.6.3
/var/lib/flatpak/runtime/org.freedesktop.Platform/x86_64/22.08/89f5b42b081f8cfcf7fbb1d858b82af06fe19681e6f6ea4c3b769dcb6c1ac295/files/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncursesw.so.6
/var/lib/flatpak/runtime/org.freedesktop.Platform/x86_64/22.08/89f5b42b081f8cfcf7fbb1d858b82af06fe19681e6f6ea4c3b769dcb6c1ac295/files/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncursesw.so.6.3
/var/lib/flatpak/runtime/org.freedesktop.Platform/x86_64/24.08/52eee7d3424a54894fa84c360997e9f00d19dc105fd247ce3931f4da157bdd4d/files/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncurses.so.6
/var/lib/flatpak/runtime/org.freedesktop.Platform/x86_64/24.08/52eee7d3424a54894fa84c360997e9f00d19dc105fd247ce3931f4da157bdd4d/files/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncurses.so.6.4
/var/lib/flatpak/runtime/org.freedesktop.Platform/x86_64/24.08/52eee7d3424a54894fa84c360997e9f00d19dc105fd247ce3931f4da157bdd4d/files/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncursesw.so.6
/var/lib/flatpak/runtime/org.freedesktop.Platform/x86_64/24.08/52eee7d3424a54894fa84c360997e9f00d19dc105fd247ce3931f4da157bdd4d/files/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncursesw.so.6.4
/var/lib/flatpak/runtime/org.freedesktop.Platform.Compat.i386/x86_64/24.08/13a475e4f3acd765670c56b20c395dd8e9484c57886126f4cd02c91021ed2319/files/libncurses.so.6
/var/lib/flatpak/runtime/org.freedesktop.Platform.Compat.i386/x86_64/24.08/13a475e4f3acd765670c56b20c395dd8e9484c57886126f4cd02c91021ed2319/files/libncurses.so.6.4
/var/lib/flatpak/runtime/org.freedesktop.Platform.Compat.i386/x86_64/24.08/13a475e4f3acd765670c56b20c395dd8e9484c57886126f4cd02c91021ed2319/files/libncursesw.so.6
/var/lib/flatpak/runtime/org.freedesktop.Platform.Compat.i386/x86_64/24.08/13a475e4f3acd765670c56b20c395dd8e9484c57886126f4cd02c91021ed2319/files/libncursesw.so.6.4
/var/lib/flatpak/runtime/org.gnome.Platform/x86_64/45/541bff0c2aa0dd74f25fae558ec8ae2f5c58ea37e7a6579bf0d06f01f5a3898a/files/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncurses.so.6
/var/lib/flatpak/runtime/org.gnome.Platform/x86_64/45/541bff0c2aa0dd74f25fae558ec8ae2f5c58ea37e7a6579bf0d06f01f5a3898a/files/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncurses.so.6.4
/var/lib/flatpak/runtime/org.gnome.Platform/x86_64/45/541bff0c2aa0dd74f25fae558ec8ae2f5c58ea37e7a6579bf0d06f01f5a3898a/files/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncursesw.so.6
/var/lib/flatpak/runtime/org.gnome.Platform/x86_64/45/541bff0c2aa0dd74f25fae558ec8ae2f5c58ea37e7a6579bf0d06f01f5a3898a/files/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncursesw.so.6.4
/var/lib/flatpak/runtime/org.gnome.Platform/x86_64/46/7baeb8503e6a4493e25190a66ad955088789a5d3dd0b99c3a3a972089e5eba68/files/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncurses.so.6
/var/lib/flatpak/runtime/org.gnome.Platform/x86_64/46/7baeb8503e6a4493e25190a66ad955088789a5d3dd0b99c3a3a972089e5eba68/files/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncurses.so.6.4
/var/lib/flatpak/runtime/org.gnome.Platform/x86_64/46/7baeb8503e6a4493e25190a66ad955088789a5d3dd0b99c3a3a972089e5eba68/files/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncursesw.so.6
/var/lib/flatpak/runtime/org.gnome.Platform/x86_64/46/7baeb8503e6a4493e25190a66ad955088789a5d3dd0b99c3a3a972089e5eba68/files/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncursesw.so.6.4
/var/lib/flatpak/runtime/org.kde.Platform/x86_64/5.15-23.08/4d49c450514df9f8cfa5fe1a83b9e5cebe1fc2c9b958e8cabe4b1a23f4068d7c/files/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncurses.so.6
/var/lib/flatpak/runtime/org.kde.Platform/x86_64/5.15-23.08/4d49c450514df9f8cfa5fe1a83b9e5cebe1fc2c9b958e8cabe4b1a23f4068d7c/files/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncurses.so.6.4
/var/lib/flatpak/runtime/org.kde.Platform/x86_64/5.15-23.08/4d49c450514df9f8cfa5fe1a83b9e5cebe1fc2c9b958e8cabe4b1a23f4068d7c/files/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncursesw.so.6
/var/lib/flatpak/runtime/org.kde.Platform/x86_64/5.15-23.08/4d49c450514df9f8cfa5fe1a83b9e5cebe1fc2c9b958e8cabe4b1a23f4068d7c/files/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncursesw.so.6.4
"

so im guessing i have to link this with the "so" command? how do i do that exactly i have some idea and where do i link the search directory for the SH script does it need to be linked specifically to some location? and how do i find out where this location is?
also will there be any issues if im linking to version 6.4? when its looking for version 5?
   yuks@puks:~/Downloads/linux$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

have tried this
Code: Select all

yuks@puks:~/Downloads/linux$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
yuks@puks:~/Downloads/linux$ ./run.sh
./adb: error while loading shared libraries: libncurses.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

./adb: error while loading shared libraries: libncurses.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
yuks@puks:~/Downloads/linux$ cd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
yuks@puks:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu$ sudo ln -s libncurses.so.6 libncurses.so.5
[sudo] password for yuks:         
yuks@puks:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu$ ls -l | grep libncurses.so.5
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root        15 Dec  4 17:27 libncurses.so.5 -> libncurses.so.6
yuks@puks:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu$ cd ~/Downloads/linux
./run.sh
./adb: error while loading shared libraries: libncurses.so.5: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64

./adb: error while loading shared libraries: libncurses.so.5: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
yuks@puks:~/Downloads/linux$ 

so what do i do now?
